# How to get the functionality of sqlplus' "BREAK ON" in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, psql, sqlplus

Is there a way to separate a query that has a group by attribute in Postgres in a fashion similar to `sqlplus`?

Assuming I have branches of my company in every country, is there a way to have a separate table for the branches of every country?

In `sqlplus` I would use `break on country`.

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ON (...)`?

Comment: You can't. `psql` isn't intended to generate (plain text) reports the way `sqlplus` does.